# Laravel 8 behaviour Logout itself

Tags: php, laravel, session

My web application has a strange/weird behaviour. Whenever i log-in into the apps, everything fine. After click few times menu, it gets logout. My apps is running well without any weird that behaviour in development local.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'app','as' => 'app.'],function(){
......
```

i use default auth middleware from laravel. i also change session driver from `file` to `database` but still have a problem with that weird behaviour of logout. My applications used to put in the shared hosting, and right now moved into the cloud. I have no issue before in shared hosting. But after moving into the cloud this is what happens.

note: i also have try change the cookies name but still got nothing.

here is the config session file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),
    'http_only' => true,
    'same_site' => 'lax',
];
```

Comment: Did you check lifetime of the session?

Comment: the life time was default at 120. But that behaviour of logout perform before 120

Comment: Can you show us config/session.php

Comment: check it, i put the code on the thread